# Setting the style of QFrame

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have a QFrame, titled 'bannerframe' embedded in a dialog, with other widgets.

I want to dynamically change the background of the frame. If I use a stylesheet defined in the top level dialog (MessageDlg), it appears correctly, like this: -

[image: Correct gradient]

The stylesheet is defined as

```
#bannerFrame
{
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, 
                                    stop:0 rgba(195, 40, 9, 255), 
                                    stop:0.7 rgba(225, 121, 113, 255), 
                                    stop:1 rgba(237, 154, 152, 255));
}
```

However, if I remove this and add the style directly to the bannerframe widget, the gradient doesn't seem to work properly: -

[image: Bad gradient]

The same effect is seen, regardless of setting the stylesheet in the Designer, or in code:

```
QString style = QString("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,\
                           stop:0 rgba(%1, %2, %3, 255),\
                           stop:1 rgba(%4, %5, %6, 255));").arg(red1).arg(green1).arg(blue1).arg(red2).arg(green2).arg(blue2);

ui->bannerFrame->setStyleSheet(style);
```

So, what's going on here?

Why does the gradient not work correctly around the frame's widgets when the stylesheet is set directly on the Frame, rather than on the top-level dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because the widgets in the frame will inherit their parents stylesheet. So what you see is the QLabel widget with the icon having a gradient background. Add a selector to limit the widgets your styles should apply to.

```
QString style = QString("QFrame {...}");
```

or

```
QString style = QString("QFrame#bannerFrame {...}");
```

Comment: Thanks, I see. I'd not defined the #bannerFrame when setting it directly on the frame. I assumed that it would not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to deal with that too until I discovered that Qt style is decided by the LAST line that sets a style. That means that if you have

```
something->setStyleSheet(Style1);
something->setStyleSheet(Style2);
something->setStyleSheet(Style3);
```

Only Style 3 will remain (If they are equal but changing values. If there are diferences, i.e style1 puts text in Bold and style2 puts text in size 14, they will both work BUT if style3 says that text size is 17, then it will be 17.

To avoid that and be able to change it for every type of widget, you need to define for who is that style:

```
generallayout->setStyleSheet("NAME{css_code}");
```

like:

```
 myLayout->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{background-color:#ff0066"};
```

with that only LineEdits will have that background. In your case, you just need to use QFrame or QFrame#bannerFrame depending on what you want.

Comment: That's crazy. One would assume that if you set it directly on a particular widget, the name would not be needed. Thanks.

Comment: yes yes i know, I had to handle with that sooo much time and did some little (or big xd) odd job to fix it until I realized what was happening there... u.u it's a bit tricky qt in that way hehe (In fact my case was the same as yours, with other widgets but same double background line)

Comment: Sorry, for accepting and then removing it. @mikag was absolutely correct on what was wrong in code and since he answered first, I thought it only right his answer should be accepted.

Comment: sure np,  I posted to let it clearer and thought u accepted it because that. Np :)

Comment: It is certainly helpful, but I don't have any other widgets with styles defined, so technically it didn't fully answer the question. Thanks though and it will hopefully help others.